# Отслеживание хуков watcher-ом

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, хук, watch

Какие хуки отслеживает watcher во Vue? Я имею ввиду Триггер watcher'ов внутри хуков жизненного цикла на https://habr.com/ru/companies/constanta/articles/435700/.  Пытался искать в документации - не нашел. Если есть (плохо искал),то приведите ссылку.

Comment: watch не отслеживает хуки. Для отслеживания хуков есть специальные вызовы.

Comment: @ВикторКарев я имел ввиду Триггер watcher'ов внутри хуков жизненного цикла
 на https://habr.com/ru/companies/constanta/articles/435700/. Можете привести ссылку на документацию к этому примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Вот документация: https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html
В статье есть обяснения, но требуются некоторые уточнения.

Итак, что у нас происходит?

Создание объекта:

1. Объект инициализируется.
2. Вызывается хук **beforeCreate**, amount=1, но механизмы слежения не установлены.
3. Экземпляр завершает настройку, устанавливает слежение
4. Вызывается хук **created**, amount=2, флаг изменения amount поднят.
5. Компилируется шаблон или функция render.
6. Вызывается хук **beforeMount**, amount=3, флаг изменения amount поднят.
7. Объект монтируется
8. Вызывается хук **mounted**, amount=4, флаг изменения amount поднят.
9. Начинается новый тик, срабатывает watcher, выводит в лог 4.

Удаление:

1. Вызывается хук **beforeUnmount**, amount=5, флаг изменения amount поднят.
2. Объект размонтируется, уничтожаются механизмы слежения.
3. Вызывается хук **unmounted**, amount=6, слежение отсутствует.
4. Начинается новый тик, никакого слежения нет, в лог ничего не выводится.

В результате в логе имеем только цифру 4